# Check if Auth has a certain middleware

Tags: php, laravel

When adding a middleware to a route, a visitor needs to "pass" that middleware before the visitor can see the resulting page.
I want to know if and how I can check if a user would theoretically pass an arbitrary middleware (that he did not need for his current request)

I.e.

I have 3 middleware `1`, `2` and `3`

My route has middleware `1` and `2` enabled, how would I check if the user would pass middleware `3`?

Comment: Add more details, you mean how to check route has certain middleware?

Comment: I've made it very clear. I want to check if the visitor HAS a middleware INSIDE a view. I never mentioned anything about a route?

Comment: There is no such thing as middleware inside a view.

Comment: I downvoted because as it currently stands, it isn't a very good question. What have you tried? Middleware is applied before a view/destination is hit isn't it?

Comment: Dees that isn't what I asked at all, I asked how can I check if a visitor HAS a middle (passed a middleware) inside a view.

Comment: route has middlewares, not visitor

Comment: Well that would depend on the constraints of the middleware wouldn't it?

Comment: Andy, only ones the user required to view the current page, and I haven't tried anything. If I had tried anything don't you think I would of posted that?

Comment: If the users has already reached the view, you know he passed the middleware.

Comment: Dees as I have previously said, a specific middleware, not the one required for that page.

Comment: You can't. That isn't what middlewares are for. "Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application". Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware).

Comment: If you haven't tried anything how are we able to fully help? Kindly explain what the "specific" middleware is and how its intended to work and maybe we can help you

Comment: But even the docs say "Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application." as Dees said above, your middleware is applied before you hit a view. I guess you could use a middleware to set some sort of flag depending on the reason for using it but I still don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Heres what you could do, you could declare a function to check what ever your middleware would originally check like below

```
public function passesTest() {
    return true; // check something here
}
```

Then you should be able to check if the user passes it using the below code which the function can be accessed inside the middleware and your view.

```
if (Auth::passesTest()) {
    // do something
}
```

That way, you only have to change it in 1 place if you ever want to modify it.

Comment: What if Laravel pushes an update and you run `composer update`? The code would be lost.

Comment: @DeesOomens not if you use a custom Auth class.

Answer (score 4):

As other users tried to explain to you in the comments, Middleware is not the proper tool for this. Middleware is used to check any given request before it reaches any view.

You could use a [custom guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-guards), this will enable you to use auth checking as suggested by @distribut0n.

Inside this custom auth guard you could use the `Request` facade to access information necessary and of course you could use the `Auth::user()` for further info, the combination of these two items should give you the ability to check almost any possible request.

To prevent duplicate code it might be better to only declare the logic in your custom guard and use that to check in your middleware.